# Gulp - When to return a value and when not to

Tags: gulp

Gulp 4. This snippet adapted from a tutorial returns something from `src` or `pipe`, I actually don't even know that part (I don't do much JS).

```
function jquery() {
    return gulp.src(["node_modules/jquery/dist/**/*.*"])
        .pipe(gulp.dest("wwwroot/lib/jquery/dist"));
};
gulp.task(jquery);
```

I want to add another copy task, which means adding another `src` and `pipe` but that means no longer returning from the first one and I guess returning from the second one, but will I see errors happening on the first?

Like this:

```
function jquery() {
    gulp.src(["node_modules/jquery/dist/**/*.*"])
        .pipe(gulp.dest("wwwroot/lib/jquery/dist"));

    return gulp.src(["node_modules/jquery-validation/dist/**/*.*"])
        .pipe(gulp.dest("wwwroot/lib/jquery-validation/dist"));
};
gulp.task(jquery);
```

I notice some tasks in samples don't return anything. I've also noticed that the Gulp documentation wants me to call a callback to indicate completion `cb()` (why don't they call it `complete()`? JS bugs me) but not seen this in people's blogged tutorials.

Confused.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting there.

```
[11:38:33] Using gulpfile C:\DATA\Git\MA\src\Analytics.Quest.Web.Pages\gulpfile.js
[11:38:33] Starting 'staticfiles'...
[11:38:33] The following tasks did not complete: staticfiles
[11:38:33] Did you forget to signal async completion?
```

I notice Gulp helpfully moans when I don't call `cb()` or `done()` as I called it. Returning a stream from a pipe seems to silence this warning, too, but I don't know why I should return a stream yet and what to do when I have two streams and only the second is returned, or what uses it.

---

I've given up not knowing whether calls to `gulp.src(...).pipe(...)` are blocking or async and have just stuck each bunch of stuff I want to copy into its own function and task, then stuck them all in a `parallel`.

Like this.

```
function jquery() {
    return gulp.src(["node_modules/jquery/dist/**/*.*"])
        .pipe(gulp.dest("wwwroot/lib/jquery/dist"));
};
gulp.task(jquery);


function jqueryValidation() {
    return gulp.src(["node_modules/jquery-validation/dist/**/*.*"])
        .pipe(gulp.dest("wwwroot/lib/jquery-validation/dist"));
};
gulp.task(jqueryValidation);


function jqueryValidationUnobtrusive() {
    return gulp.src(["node_modules/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/dist/**/*.*"])
        .pipe(gulp.dest("wwwroot/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/dist"));
};
gulp.task(jqueryValidationUnobtrusive);


function jqueryValidationUnobtrusiveBootstrap() {
    return gulp.src(["node_modules/jquery-validation-unobtrusive-bootstrap/dist/**/*.*"])
        .pipe(gulp.dest("wwwroot/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive-bootstrap/dist"));
};
gulp.task(jqueryValidationUnobtrusiveBootstrap);


function jqueryAll(done) {
    parallel(jquery, jqueryValidation, jqueryValidationUnobtrusive, jqueryValidationUnobtrusiveBootstrap);
    done();
}
gulp.task(jqueryAll);
```